# how to enter in this table number OF pupils for the chosen year and a class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I save year, a class. I don't know as to save number of pupils. How to enter in this table number OF pupils for the chosen year and a class? In the table YearClass it is necessary to keep number of pupils for this course which chose in shape.

**Model**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :class
end

class Class < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :year_classes, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :years, :through => :year_classes
      has_many :students
    end

    class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :year_classes, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :classes, :through => :year_classes
    end

    class YearClass < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :year
      belongs_to :class
    end
```

**view**

```
<table>

  <%= f.select(:class_id, @classes.map{|p| [p.id]}) %>

  <%= f.select(:year_id, @years.map{|p| [p.name, p.id]}) %>

  <%= f.text_field :count_stud, :value => "#{@count}" %>

</table>
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @count = Student.count
    @classes = Class.all
    @years = Year.all

        @year_class = YearClass.new(year_class_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @year_class.save
            format.html { redirect_to @year_class, notice: 'Student was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @year_class }
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @year_class.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end

        end
      end
```

Comment: How would we know? how does `Student` interact with `Year` _or_ `Class`? Are we supposed to _know_ that? Are we supposed to _guess_ that?

Comment: many-to-many association

Comment: Great! and Students are...

Comment: Add students! Help me!

Comment: Students don't appear to be associated with Years in any way. Since Students only belong to a Class and a Class can have many Years, your program does not know which students belong in which years.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your model, it is impossible to know "number OF pupils for the chosen year and a class", since there is no association between `Student` and `Year`, which means that there is no way to tell how many `Student`s enrolled in a given `Class` in a given `Year`.

If you change your `Student` model to have an association to both (through `YearClass` maybe?) you could devise a query that will return what you want:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :year_class
end

class YearClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :year
  belongs_to :class
  has_many :students
end
```

Now you can ask:

```
@year_class = YearClass.find_by(year: @year, class: @class)
@student_count = @year_class ? @year_class.students.count : 0
```

`@student_count` will be `nil` if there is no `YearClass` for the given year and class... I'm not sure what you should put in your view, as it is not clear what you want to be there...

Comment: def create                                                          @student_count = YearClass.find_by(year_id: @year, class_id: @class).map do |yc|
      yc.students.count
    end.inject(:+)                                                  I have a mistake on undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass           and what write in view?

Comment: @user3554457 - I've had a bug in my code, sorry. I can't answer what should be in the view, since it is not clear what you want it to do

Comment: I have a following mistake PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column students.year_class_id does not exist LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" WHERE "students"."year_cour... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "students" WHERE "students"."year_class_id" = $1

Comment: YearClass includes 3 fields: class_id, year_id and count_student.

Comment: I've no idea what you did to have that, and I think this is getting to be a little too broad for this scope. I suggest you learn a bit about databases, and rails, and javascript, and then take another stab at this...

Comment: Question in other how to write it in representation. Help with a line.How to substitute the @student_count variable in the field of text_field

Comment: <%= f.text_field :stud_count, @student_count %> - How it is correct to write this line.

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_field - once you have it... What I suspect, though, is that you want it to magically change as you select different years or classes - and unfortunately, it is not that easy. It involves JavaScript and maybe Ajax...